# While evaluating length of a list that is defined as a class

Tags: python, class, oop

For example, I got a class named `stack`,

```
class stack: #Will be used for probable files!
    def __init__(self):
            self.data = []

    def add(self, element):
            self.data.append(element)

    def number_of_elements(self):
            return len(self.data)

    def stackType(self):
        if self.number_of_elements == 0:
            return 0
        elif self.number_of_elements == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return -1
```

I then do this:

```
foo = stack()
print foo.stackType()
```

I get `-1` however I was expecting a return of `1`

Why is it so and how can I handle with it?

Answer (score 3):

That's because you did not call the *call* the method `self.number_of_elements`; you merely tested to see if it equalled `0` or `1`.

Modify your code to actually call the method using this syntax: `self.number_of_elements()` [notice the use of `()` to call the method]:

```
def stackType(self) :
        if self.number_of_elements() == 0 :
                return 0
        elif self.number_of_elements() == 1 :
                return 1
        else :
                return -1
```

You could also have written it like this:

```
def stack_type(self):
    n = self.number_of_elements()
    return -1 if n > 1 else n
```

which would be an improvement because `number_of_elements()` will be called *once* only. In your code the method could be called twice. I renamed the function to be consistent with the Python method naming conventions set out in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names).

Answer (score 1):

Because `self.number_of_elements` is not the same as `self.number_of_elements()`!

The former is a reference to the function, the latter is a call to the function actually calculating the length of your stack.

Answer (score 0):

self.number_of_elements is a function, so its value is neither zero nor 1